# Download previous versions of Titanium SDK

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I recently had to format my Mac and lost all my Ti sdks.
After Reinstalling Appcelerator Studio I currently have only Ti SDK 5.2.0.GA available which is causing my app to crash on devices having Android Marshmallow which didn't happen on 5.0.0.GA or below. Is there anyway I can install the previous version of Titanium SDK's and use it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way, via **[CLI](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference)** (command line interface).

[Get](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-SDKList) the SDK titanium list

```
appc ti sdk list
```

[Install](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-SDKInstall) titanium SDK

```
appc ti sdk install [<version>] [--default] [--force] [--branch <branch name>]

ex : appc ti sdk install 9.2.1.GA
```

Available SDK with **appc**

[image]

Appc info [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-43294287_AppceleratorCommand-LineInterfaceReference-install)

Answer (score 4):

Above solution is correct, But for above steps you want appc username and password.
 If you dont have user name and password then try next command.

`titanium sdk`
[image]

`titanium sdk install 5.2.0`

`after installing check`

`titanium sdk`
[image]

If you downloaded sdk from other sources and now you have to put sdk in your titanium path then go to following path

`/Users/rahul/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk`

and place your downloaded sdk in above folder.
[image]